# how to check browser's request in VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, browser, request, availability

I need to check browser in `VB.NET`, so that I can use that in an `IF - ELSE` condition.

Something like this:

```
IF(!IE){//do this }.
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`** Dim bc As HttpBrowserCapabilities = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser**`

I have used the above statement and that worked for me!
As it was not finding the httpcontext I used the above statement.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Request object has a browser property you could reference.

```
    Request.Browser.Browser
```

Will give you the browser that you'll have to then check to see if it is IE.

You're syntax leads me to believe that this is a JavaScript or C# question.  If it is JavaScript, there are plenty of libraries out there to detect browsers client side.  A quick example is..

```
   var browser = navigator.appName;
```

Comment: Thanks Howie for your reply.I am using VB.NET language.
 I tried `Request.Browser.Browser ='IE'` but the code is breaking at the above line and I am getting this error : `System.web.httpException:Request is not available in this context`

Comment: Are you using ASP.net MVC, WebForms, etc?  Where is this call being made?  If using MVC is it within your view or your controller method?

Comment: Its a project on ASP.net WebForms with VB.NET as the development language.
Initially when I was using `Request.Browser.Browser`I was getting error `"The Name request is not declared "`  
Might be this was due to namespace issue that has been solved by inheriting one template in the project.  
But Now the code is breaking at the above mentioned line.